# A regular graph G of degree r where G has n=3r vertices. Prove G has no Bridge

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

A regular graph G of degree r where G has n=3r vertices. Prove G has no Bridge.

Does anyone have a hint?

Comment: @bof yes, a regular graph, I am sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $e$ is a bridge, so that $G-e$ has two components, $G_1$ and $G_2.$ Say $G_1$ has $n_1$ vertices and $G_2$ has $n_2$ vertices. So $G_1$ has $\frac{rn_1-1}2$ edges, and $G_2$ has $\frac{rn_2-1}2$ edges. So $rn_1$ and $rn_2$ are odd, and $n_1+n_2=3r.$ So $r,n_1,n_2$ are all odd, so $n_1+n_2$ is even, so $3r$ is even, so $r$ is even. . . oops!

Comment: Nice one! But I think in the end it should read '3r is even, so r is even...'

Comment: Of course. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: @MaxPunck-Institut  I was trying a naive approach. Could you tell me if my approach is good. I want to show that either G has exactly one cycle C and are edges of G are in C OR G has x cycles and all edges are in at least one cycle.

Comment: Hey can you help me with a similar question

Comment: G is k-regular with n=r^2 vertices. What is the minimum edge connectivity of G